# How can I get all the information about this account

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have tried many, many times to solve this error, but it is useless
I just want to get the other names on this account and they are all linked through id of account
I've tried this code, but it only shows me the first user

[image]

```
    connectionMenu.ConnectionString = "server=192.168.1.100;user id=root;Password=123456789;persist security info=True;database=player"
    Try
        connectionMenu.Open()
        mysqlcmdMenu.Connection = connectionMenu
        mysqlcmdMenu.CommandText = "Select *FROM player.player Where account_id='" & Login.Label2.Text & "'"
        Dim readerfill = mysqlcmdMenu.ExecuteReader
        If readerfill.Read() Then

            Label4.Text = readerfill("name")
            Label1.Text = readerfill("name")
            Label2.Text = readerfill("name")
            Label3.Text = readerfill("name")
        Else
            MsgBox("There is no User at this account")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("error " + ex.Message)
    Finally
        connectionMenu.Close()
        connectionMenu.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Attention : Login.Label2.text = id account

Thanks to all

Comment: You will need to loop through your reader results if you want more than just the first row 

Comment: Try to loop through your result if found and show names on label text

Comment: Of course it only shows you the first user, because you're only reading the first record, if you have done any research on using data readers then you know that every call to `Read` reads a single record from the result set. If you want to read multiple records then you need to call `Read` multiple times. The documentation for the `MySqlDataReader` class even contains a code example that does just that so there's no excuse for not knowing. You should NEVER be asking a question here without having read the relevant documentation first.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your connections and commands in the method where they are used. Your database objects need to be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for us.

Don't open the connection until directly before the `.Execute...`

**Always** use parameters to build sql strings to avoid sql injection. **Never** concatenate strings.

Don't update the user interface with a `DataReader`. A `DataReader` requires an open connection and you don't want to hold a connection open this long.

I have separated the database code from the user interface code. This should make it easier to maintain.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Try
        dt = GetPlayerData(Login.Label2.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
    'I am guessing that "name" is a name of a field
    Label4.Text = dt(0)("name").ToString
    Label1.Text = dt(1)("name").ToString
    Label2.Text = dt(2)("name").ToString
    Label3.Text = dt(3)("name").ToString
End Sub

Private Function GetPlayerData(ID As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select *FROM player.player Where account_id= @ID;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```